# ionic beta error when trying to create sample project from github

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic2

I am using windows 10 and I am trying to create an ionic project using the sample template on the github, but I am getting the following error:

> D:\Programming Exercise\mobile\ionic2Samples>ionic start MyIonic2Project tutorial --v2 --ts
>   One awesome Ionic app coming right up...
>   Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/typescript.zip
>   Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-tutorial/archive/typescript.zip
>   Installing Node Modules
>   Unable to run exec commandError: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "npm install"
>   npm WARN MyIonic2Project No description
>   npm WARN MyIonic2Project No repository field.
>   npm WARN MyIonic2Project No license field.
>   npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
>   npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
>   npm ERR! node v5.6.0
>   npm ERR! npm  v3.6.0
>   npm ERR! path D:\Programming Exercise\mobile\ionic2Samples\MyIonic2Project\node_modules\json5\lib\cli.js
>   npm ERR! code ENOENT
>   npm ERR! errno -4058
>   npm ERR! syscall chmod
>   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'D:\Programming Exercise\mobile\ionic2Samples\MyIonic2Project\node_modules\json5\lib\cli.js'
>   npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod 'D:\Programming Exercise\mobile\ionic2Samples\MyIonic2Project\node_modules\json5\lib\cli.js'
>   npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>   npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
>   npm ERR! enoent
>   npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     D:\Programming Exercise\mobile\ionic2Samples\MyIonic2Project\npm-debug.log
>    (CLI v2.0.0-beta.17)
>   Your system information:
>   Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
>   Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.17
>   Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.8
>   OS:
>   Node Version: v5.6.0***

Comment: i have similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884044/npm-error-after-update-ionic-2

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem here: [Npm error after update ionic 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884044/npm-error-after-update-ionic-2/35909947#35909947) but now is solved.

You can see my answer, but try this:

1. Uninstall ionic and cordova with: `npm uninstall -g ionic cordova`
2. Uninstall nodejs with the windows installer/uninstaller or use something like [IObit Uninstaller](http://www.iobit.com/en/advanceduninstaller.php) to perform a clean and complete uninstall.
3. Manually remove the **npm-cache** folder located in `C:\Users\{YourUserNameHere}\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache` (in my case `npm cache clean` doesn't work)
4. Restart your PC and now install [nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/), you can see that now there is a new version **v5.8.0** and works perfect with ionic (at least for me).
5. Install ionic and cordova: `npm install -g cordova ionic@beta` and have fun!

Like i see in your errors, you tried **v5.6.0** node version and **2.0.0-beta.17** ionic version, try now with **v5.8.0** and **2.0.0-beta.19** which are the last versions at the moment.

P.S: Ofcourse don't forget to open the **cmd.exe** or whatever command prompt you are using, as **Administrator**.

P.S2: Sorry if my english isn't perfect, but you will understand me.

Comment: Just updating Nodejs from 4.3.2 to 5.7.1 has fixed the problem for me - I didn't need to do the other steps.

Comment: Nice, yeah this steps are maybe if the update is not working. Remember that now is in 5.8.0, and at least for me... is working perfect with ionic 2!