# Npm error after update ionic 2

Tags: node.js, cordova, npm, ionic2

I get an error when i want to start an app project in ionic 2 with:

```
ionic start name blank --v2
```

Here the error:

```
One awesome Ionic app coming right up...

Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-app-base/archive/master.zip
[=============================]  100%  0.0s
Downloading: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic2-starter-blank/archive/master.zip
Installing Node Modules

Unable to run exec commandError: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /s /c "npm install"
npm WARN package.json @ No description
npm WARN package.json @ No repository field.
npm WARN package.json @ No README data
npm WARN package.json @ No license field.
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.8
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@3.0.8: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated lodash@1.0.2: lodash@<3.0.0 is no longer maintained. Upgrade to lodash@^4.0.0.
npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: graceful-fs version 3 and before will fail on newer node releases. Please update to graceful-fs@^4.0.0 as soon as possible.
npm WARN deprecated npmconf@2.1.2: this package has been reintegrated into npm and is now out of date with respect to npm
npm WARN optional dep failed, continuing fsevents@1.0.8
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10586
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.3.2
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Next-Version\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\xtend\4.0.1\package\package.json.9c277ab6532ec69d68e9da8f764c6a72
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall rename

npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Next-Version\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\xtend\4.0.1\package\package.json.9c277ab6532ec69d68e9da8f764c6a72' -> 'C:\Users\Next-Version\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\xtend\4.0.1\package\package.json'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'C:\Users\Next-Version\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\xtend\4.0.1\package\package.json.9c277ab6532ec69d68e9da8f764c6a72' -> 'C:\Users\Next-Version\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\xtend\4.0.1\package\package.json']
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'rename',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Next-Version\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\xtend\\4.0.1\\package\\package.json.9c277ab6532ec69d68e9da8f764c6a72',
npm ERR!   dest: 'C:\\Users\\Next-Version\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm-cache\\xtend\\4.0.1\\package\\package.json',
npm ERR!   parent: 'through2' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\devcenter\rrpp\npm-debug.log
 (CLI v2.0.0-beta.19)

Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
Ionic Version: 2.0.0-beta.3
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.19
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.9
OS:
Node Version: v4.3.2
```

I tried uninstalling and installing nodejs and ionic/cordova two times but getting the same result. When i tried ionic 2 before worked perfect, but not after update to last version.

Any help? Thanks!

P.S: i have Windows 10 x64

Comment: try running the terminal as admin. right click on cmd and select `Run as Administrator`

Comment: This is not the problem @Patrioticcow i did it as administrator. Now i am trying uninstalling my antivirus.

Comment: that might be so, but that is the error i see in your log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.

I updated nodejs to version 5.8.0 from version 4.

Apart from this, I manually removed the npm-cache folder. 
I think `npm cache clean` did not work.

If you are having the same issue see my answer in a similar post with more instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35910287/2012904

Comment: I removed manually the npm-cache folder and after that it work! Thanks @aluknot